# Identify start and end of Data received by TCPClient and get complete data packet C#

Tags: c#, winforms, tcp, tcpclient

Hi all i am Writing a prog. to receive the data from static IP and Port i have reached establishing connection to that IP and receiving the data but i am not getting complete data as i need please help in resolving the problem below is my code

```
  TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient();
```

`clientSocket.Connect("x.x.x.x", 1111);`

```
        if (clientSocket.Connected)
        {

            NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            while (true)
            {
                while (serverStream.DataAvailable)
                {

                    // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    byte[] inStream = new byte[1000768];
                    serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                    //serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, 1000768);
                    string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
                    if (true)// returndata.Substring(0, 1) == "$" && returndata.Substring(51, 1) == "~"
                    {
                        Invoke(new testDelegate(test), new object[] { returndata.Trim() });
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

my server sends

> $01SSAA,25.64,414.47,12.164;~$02SSA,216.12,414.153,13.019;~

as response and i need to store it but i am not getting full response every time.  i am getting it broken like only

- $01SSAA,,25.64,44 or 12.64;~$0SSAA,,

or

- $01SSAA,25.624,44.417,121.641;~$02SSAA,2116.121,414.5113

but when i use telnet and IP port i get full response

Comment: That's how TCP works. _You_ need to implement a protocol on top of it. Obviously, you have something to work with, so: time to figure out how the messages are separated and then do so.

Comment: @Fildor will you guide with some example

Comment: Without knowing the byte content, _it looks as if_ messages start with "$##" where "##" is some sort of id or number and they end with ";~" ...

Comment: but when I use telnet and IP port i get full response on new line after every 5 seconds

Comment: Basically: 1. You read what's in the current buffer. 2. You add (append!) it to your internal buffer. 3. You extract all complete messages and deliver them to the upper layers, while leaving incomplete messages in the internal buffer to be appended to in the next read cycle. 4. Back to 1.

Comment: Is your TCP data delimited by newlines?

Comment: telnet is a whole different protocol. Messages are complete, because lines are `\n` - terminated. That _may_ be part of the (application) protocol, maybe not. Point is: It doesn't matter for the way TCP reads data. It doesn't wait for line terminators.

Comment: @CaiusJard i can identify data between ($) and (~)  example $01SSAA,25.64,414.47,12.164;~

Comment: Don't you have a Protocol Documentation (you should) ?

Comment: So the data comes as a stream like `$helloblah~$hellomoreblah~` ? Perhaps the simplest way would be to stream it through your own stream implementation that replaces `~` with `\n` and use a streamreader to read it line by line, or extend StreamReader (code is at https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs) to add a method that takes a delimiter char of what a line is, rather than fixing on \r or \n

Comment: yes but i receive it in broken format like $hello  ,   Blah~$hithis  , $helloblah~$hello like wise

Comment: I'm not really asking how you receive it, I'm asking how the server sends it. Does the server reliably always send `$message1~$message2~$message3~` etc

Comment: yes server sends like that

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at ReadLine out of [StreamReader](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs):

```
        // Reads a line. A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by
        // a carriage return ('\r'), a line feed ('\n'), or a carriage return
        // immediately followed by a line feed. The resulting string does not
        // contain the terminating carriage return and/or line feed. The returned
        // value is null if the end of the input stream has been reached.
        //
        public override String ReadLine()
        {
            if (stream == null)
                __Error.ReaderClosed();
 
#if FEATURE_ASYNC_IO
            CheckAsyncTaskInProgress();
#endif
 
            if (charPos == charLen)
            {
                if (ReadBuffer() == 0) return null;
            }
 
            StringBuilder sb = null;
            do {
                int i = charPos;
                do {
                    char ch = charBuffer[i];
                    // Note the following common line feed chars:
                    // \n - UNIX   \r\n - DOS   \r - Mac
                    if (ch == '\r' || ch == '\n') {
                        String s;
                        if (sb != null) {
                            sb.Append(charBuffer, charPos, i - charPos);
                            s = sb.ToString();
                        }
                        else {
                            s = new String(charBuffer, charPos, i - charPos);
                        }
                        charPos = i + 1;
                        if (ch == '\r' && (charPos < charLen || ReadBuffer() > 0)) {
                            if (charBuffer[charPos] == '\n') charPos++;
                        }
                        return s;
                    }
                    i++;
                } while (i < charLen);
                i = charLen - charPos;
                if (sb == null) sb = new StringBuilder(i + 80);
                sb.Append(charBuffer, charPos, i);
            } while (ReadBuffer() > 0);
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

You can see it's getting into some quite involved stuff; it's basically reading all the data into a buffer elsewhere in the class, then chewing through that looking at chars until it encounters a `\r` or an `\n`. If it doesn't encounter one it loads everything it has so far into a StringBuilder and reads again, so that it can keep going until it gets one. In short the StringReader is buffering stuff itself so that it can spit lines out when it needs to (when asked)

There's no problem with you extending StreamReader to put your own logic in - clone this method and swap it so it's looking for `~` rather than `\r`

```
if (ch == '~') {
```

You also **don't need** the bit that checks if "the next char is \n, if it just found an \r"

```
//this if block can go
if (ch == '\r' && (charPos < charLen || ReadBuffer() > 0))
```

I havent given the full exact code you need (as in, "here; copy paste this and it'll work") because I'm not sure whether youre using netfw or netcore - the code above is from framework, but often the [netcore classes](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/StreamReader.cs) differ a little; if you're inheriting some existing class to add functionality that is based on the existing code, it's easiest to make sure you're copying code out of the one you're using...

So the work I'm recommending you do is:

- Inherit streamreader
- Add a method (called ReadTilde?) that reads up to a `~` delimiter, based on Readline which reads up to an `\r` delimiter
- Add a constructor that is useful to you, and calls a base constructor (StreamReader has no 0 argument constructors so you need to add one that e.g. takes a stream, and calls the `base(stream)`)
- Make a new instance of your streamreader, passing the network stream into it
- Call `ReadTilde()` repeatedly to get your data chopped on tildes

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
try
        {
            byte[] inStream = new byte[1000768];
            string ReturnData;
            while (true)
            {
                using (TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient())
                {
                    clientSocket.Connect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TcpServerIP"], Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]));
                    if (clientSocket.Connected)
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                        using (NetworkStream NwServerStream = clientSocket.GetStream())
                        {
                            while (NwServerStream.DataAvailable)
                            {
                                NwServerStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                                //serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, 1000768);
                                ReturnData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
                                if (true)//returndata.Substring(0, 1) == "$" && returndata.Substring(51, 1) == "~")
                                {
                                    //Invoke(new testDelegate(SaveData), new object[] { ReturnData.Trim() });
                                    SaveDataDB(ReturnData.Substring(ReturnData.IndexOf("$01RRA"), 24), ReturnData.Substring(ReturnData.IndexOf("$02RRA"), 24));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ReturnData = string.Empty;
                    Array.Clear(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
                    GC.Collect();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally {
            GC.Collect();
        }
```