# TCP Receive does not return expected number of bytes

Tags: c#, tcp

I using TCPIP to get data from a controller. When using TCPIP to receive data, i only can get the first line on data which mean the data length is 1514, but the another line of data which is length 174 are unable to get from TCPIP Client protocol at C#. May need you guys to advise on this.

Picture Below is used Wireshark to trace the TCPIP data.

[image]

Below picture is the method used to receive data from TCPIP Client Protocol.

[image]

Thanks.

Here is how I approach to connect and get data from TCPIP. Please correct me if that was a mistake.

```
public void Connect(string ipAddress, int port)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            try
            {
                IPAdddress = ipAddress;
                Port = port;
                IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);
                IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);

                Client.BeginConnect(endPoint, new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnected), null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionThrownEventArgs args = new ExceptionThrownEventArgs();
                args.Exception = ex;
                
                if (m_ExceptionThrown != null)
                {
                    foreach (Delegate del in m_ExceptionThrown.GetInvocationList())
                    {
                        ISynchronizeInvoke syncer = del.Target as ISynchronizeInvoke;
                        if (syncer == null)
                        {
                            del.DynamicInvoke(this, args);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            syncer.BeginInvoke(del, new object[] { this, args });
                        }
                    }
                    #endregion
                }

                // SupportMethod.ShowExceptionMessage(ex, Output.EventLog);
            }
        }
    }

private void OnMessageReceived(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {           
            Metadata metadata = (Metadata)result.AsyncState;

            if (metadata.ReceiveBuf[0] == 0)
            {
                Disconnect();
            }
            else
            {
                Client.EndReceive(result);
 
                
                var e = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
                LastMessageReceived = e.GetString(metadata.ReceiveBuf).Trim('\0');
                Debug.Print("TCPRaw: " + LastMessageReceived);
                
                if (m_EchoOnReceived)
                {                        
                    Echo(LastMessageReceived);
                }
               
                MessageReceivedEventArgs args = new MessageReceivedEventArgs();
                if (m_MessageReceived != null)
                {
                    #region Fire the MessageReceived event (bound during instantiation of ClientSocket).
                    
                    foreach (Delegate del in m_MessageReceived.GetInvocationList())
                    {
                        ISynchronizeInvoke syncer = del.Target as ISynchronizeInvoke;
                        if (syncer == null)
                        {
                            del.DynamicInvoke(this, args);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            syncer.BeginInvoke(del, new object[] { this, args });
                        }
                    }
                    #endregion
                }

                // Provide additional data for the socket operation. Re-instantiate a new Metadata object.
                metadata = new Metadata();
                metadata.ReceiveBuf = new byte[m_ReceiveBufSize];

                // Continue to prepare receive data from the connected Server.
                Client.BeginReceive(
                    metadata.ReceiveBuf,
                    0,
                    metadata.ReceiveBuf.Length,
                    SocketFlags.None,
                    new AsyncCallback(OnMessageReceived),
                    metadata);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionThrownEventArgs args = new ExceptionThrownEventArgs();
            args.Exception = ex;

            
            // ExceptionThrown Event.
            if (m_ExceptionThrown != null)
            {
                #region Fire the ExceptionThrown event (bound during instantiation of ClientSocket).
                // Check the Target of each delegate in the event's invocation list, and marshal the call
                // to the target thread if that target is ISynchronizeInvoke
                // ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698889/raise-events-in-net-on-the-main-ui-thread

                foreach (Delegate del in m_ExceptionThrown.GetInvocationList())
                {
                    ISynchronizeInvoke syncer = del.Target as ISynchronizeInvoke;
                    if (syncer == null)
                    {
                        del.DynamicInvoke(this, args);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        syncer.BeginInvoke(del, new object[] { this, args });
                    }
                }
                #endregion
            }

            //  SupportMethod.ShowExceptionMessage(ex, Output.EventLog);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code as code, not image.

Comment: Oh this is asked so many times; TCP is reliable and delivers all the data that is sent. Complaints of missing data are because the developer doesn't understand they have to keep reading data until they get a full message, and that might mean patching together the contents of several reads into a buffer. If a server sends 1000 bytes, your first attempt at reading it might give you 200, then you might get 150, then 27, then 623; you got your 1000 bytes in the end after several reads; it's up to you to glue it all back together

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71466689/identify-start-and-end-of-data-received-by-tcpclient-and-get-complete-data-packe - if your messages on the wire are delimited by \r or \n you can just straight use a stream reader, or if they're delimited by something else you can use the advice in that post to customize the delimiter the reader looks for. In either case it should give you some inspiration..

Comment: Does it have to be so low level as TCP? Is it a custom protocol?

Comment: Hello @CaiusJard  Thanks for the comment. I am editing the question by adding my code how I approach to TCPIP. May I get your advise on that? Thanks.

Comment: All that code, and we still have no idea what Client truly is.. Perhaps it's a Socket, in which case I'd say this line is quite suspicious: `Client.EndReceive(result);` - EndReceive probably (definitely, if its a Socket) returns the number of bytes receved; You don't appear to capture this absolutely vital bit of info. When you say to a socket "here's a 10,000 long buffer, receive into that" and it pulls 427 bytes off the network, you kinda really need to know it pulled 427 bytes off the network

Comment: (The `Trim('\0')` call is not the right way to handle it; at best it's a waste of CPU time finding the last non-0. At worst if the server deliberately sends trailing 0, youre mangling messages)

Comment: I think i'd switch away from using Begin/End receive btw. Life is so much simpler when you get the stream from a TcpClient, hand it to a StreamReader and then just `await reader.ReadXxxAsync`. If your data is line based, and essentially delimted by \n or \r\n then ReadLineAsync makes life a doddle. Note that I;ve encountered some issues with it on \r delimited data, and I rolled my own handler for that; SR seems to have a bug where ReadLine returns the previous line, not the current, if \r is the delimiter

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks for the comment. I love to trying out see the different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For TCP/IP, when you specify the number of bytes to receive in a Receive method, it is an upper limit, not an absolute number of bytes. If you receive less than the requested number of bytes, you need to do another read and combine the results together into the data you want. This is why the Receive method allows you to specify the index into the array to put the received data. For example:

```cs
var message = new byte[myMessageSize];
var totalBytesReceived = 0;
while (totalBytesReceived < myMessageSize)
{
    var bytesReceived = socket.Receive(message, 
                                       totalBytesReceived, 
                                       myMessageSize - totalBytesReceived,
                                       SocketFlags.None);
    
    totalBytesReceived += bytesReceived;
}
```

I recommend against using BeginReceive, the callbacks are difficult to manage and most people do it wrong. Use the synchronous methods or ReceiveAsync().

Comment: Thanks @John V im posting my code in my question. May seeking for the advise.